# How to debug javascript code with Windows functions on Linux?

Tags: malware, javascript, debugging

I am a beginner in analyzing javascript code on Linux and whenever the code is for a Windows machine I cannot proceed with debugging because there are undefined functions.

Examples:

```
GetObject(_6078(1),7983()) -> error GetObject is not defined
or 
WScript[3938[43]](3999) -> error Wscript is not defined
```

Is there any way to proceed or should I draw rough conclusions (like: "this is malicious and stop") as the analysis becomes difficult to follow especially if there are calls upon calls?

What is the correct way to analyze? I am also willing to use a Windows machine if necessary. People in videos just print (easy code) but I have a sample that is almost impossible to print because these functions are hidden in calls.

Comment: Have you considered a malware sandbox, like cuckoo.ee?